# I am getting React "node:stream/web" error

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I am getting the following error related to

```
node:stream/web
```

```
module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:stream/web" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
    at /Users/evangoodwin/Projects/reactformer/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:835:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/evangoodwin/Projects/reactformer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
```

I have install react-app-rewired with the following config (all packages listed below are installed)

```
module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  Object.assign(fallback, {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url"),
  });
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);
  config.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/];
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
    enforce: "pre",
    loader: require.resolve("source-map-loader"),
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
  });
  return config;
};
```

I have also tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin